# Give an example of two holomorphic functions in a bounded domain that coincide at infinitely many points and are not identical.

Tags: complex-analysis

Give an example of two holomorphic functions in a bounded domain that coincide at infinitely many points of it and are not identical. Also consider the case that the domain is not bounded.

I have tried to do this exercise but still have not found an example. Could you give me any suggestion?

Comment: Hint: Do the second part first, in fact let the domain be all of $\mathbb C$. Also, to reduce the number of moving parts in your head, make one of the functions identically zero.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: On the real line you have encountered such examples. For example, on the bounded interval $(0,1)$ the function $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ equals $0$ infinitely many times.

Comment: will this still be true if my domain(in the set theoretic sense) was a compact subset(say $A$) of $\Bbb C$ and I required my functions to be continuous on $A$ and holomorphic on the interior of $A$?

Comment: Yes, there are certainly such examples. Consider the domain 

$$U = D(1/2,1/2) \cap \{x+iy: |y|<x^2\}.$$

Then $\sin(1/z)$ is holomorphic on $U$ and  is continuous and bounded on $\bar U\setminus \{0\}.$ The function $f(z)=z\sin(1/z)$ is then continuous on the compact set $\bar U$ (with value $0$ at $0$), and holormorphic on the interior, which is of course $U.$ We have $f=0$ on the sequence $1/n\pi, n=1,2,\dots$